# Loop в mysql 8.0.16

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужно сделать цикл для одноразовой вставки множества записей в таблицу. Писал цикл по примеру из документации MySql, однако все равно получаю сразу несколько ошибок. "Statement is not complete: expecting ';'" в конце Values, а также на двух последних End получаю "Is not valid for this position".

```sql
create procedure insertWagon(places INT, i INT)
begin
    insertLoop: LOOP
    IF i < places THEN
        insert into ticketsaccounting (DepartureDateTime, WagonNumber, PlaceNumber, Price, WagonType, `Status`, Train)
               values ('2019-05-25 22:00:00', 1, i, 300, 1, 1, 0, 1);
        set i = i+1;
    end if;
    end loop insertLoop,

end;
```

Тоже самое с while  и те же ошибки

```sql
create procedure insertWagon(places INT, i INT)
begin
    while(i < places) do
        insert into ticketsaccounting (DepartureDateTime, WagonNumber, PlaceNumber, Price, WagonType, `Status`, Train)
               values ('2019-05-25 22:00:00', 1, i, 300, 1, 1, 0, 1);
        set i = i+1;
    end while;
end;
```

Comment: А кто запятых вместо точки с запятой насажал? И небось про DELIMITER забыл.

Comment: Про DELIMITER я не просто забыл, я про него и не знал :)
Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 0):

```
SET SESSION cte_max_recursion_depth := GREATEST(100, @places - @i + 1);

WITH RECURSIVE cte AS ( SELECT @i i
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT i+1 FROM cte WHERE i < @places )
insert into ticketsaccounting (DepartureDateTime, WagonNumber, PlaceNumber, Price, WagonType, `Status`, Train)
SELECT '2019-05-25 22:00:00', 1, i, 300, 1, 1, 0, 1
FROM cte;
```

И никакой процедуры не нужно...